# Using Variables as module/array names

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

My ultimate goal is to load a comboBox with elements from different arrays (vba coded).  I have 8 different arrays and 6 option buttons.  The first 2 optionButtons are grouped to eliminate 4 arrays which leaves the last 4 grouped optionButtons to determine the actual input for the combo box.

It works like this:

```
'first grouped option buttons
maleOptionButton
femaleOptionButton

'second grouped option buttons
basketballOptionButton
footballOptionButton
soccerOptionButton
hockeyOptionButton
```

The array's as you can guess are filled with student names that play the sports.  So when the user clicks the first grouped buttons of Male/Female the click even does nothing.. however when they click the second group of option buttons of sports, it calls the same sub procedure within a module that has IF's and Else Ifs to determine the combination of buttons that were selected.

sub maleInitArray()

```
'declaration section:
Public maleSoccerArray(1 to 6) as string

'sub section
dim mike as student 'calls the class student
set mike = new student

with mike
    .name = "Michael"
    .age = 14
    .so on and so on = something
end with

maleSoccerArray(1) = mike.name
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
dim i as integer
dim l as integer
dim gender as string
dim sport as string

if inputForm.soccerOptionButton.value = true then
    if inputForm.maleOptionButton.value = true then
        gender = "male"
        sport = "maleSoccerArray"
        call male.maleInitArray    ' inits the array thats hard coded.
    else
        gender = "female"
        sport = "femaleSoccerArray"
        call female.femaleInitArray
 Else If... 
 ' the list goes on to assign variables depending on the combo boxes.

' doesn't work, but it beats using this every time
l = UBound(sport) ' Doesn't recognize "sport" as an Array  
for i = 1 to l
     ' .AddItem(gender.sport(i)) will not work as well.
     inputForm.studentComboBox.AddItem(gender.sport(i))
next i
```

Seems as though UBound(variable) and AddItem(Variable.Variable)
will not work...

I found a few things so far, but none of them have worked.. such as the application.run method and assigning the actual "male.maleSoccerArray" method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. thanks

Comment: Be more specific about which part isn't working. I gather that the last 4 lines are where you are trying to populate the combobox, but in order to help, show us the code for maleInitArray and femailInitArray.

Comment: No problem! I edited it a bit.  The copy/paste doesn't work well in these.. haha

Comment: I'm a little perplexed as to why you would hard-code the student data when you are working in Excel. Try putting that data in a worksheet and take a look at [this article about how to populate arrays from Excel ranges](http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html). Start with assuming a specific user selection (e.g. male soccer players) and once you have the combobox code working then move on to populating it with different sets of students depending on the user's selection.

Comment: Haha.. I know hard coding the data while working in excel is a bit goofy.  I just wanted to see if it worked this way as well.  I can take out the variables and use the loop in every then/else statement and it works just fine.  Again.. just seeing if it can be done or not =)

Comment: Haha... It can't be, to do this you need reflection which is not available in VBA. Also `dim sport as string` and then `l = UBound(sport)`, how??

Comment: You could store the arrays in a Collection or Dictionary, then you could use the key ("male" or "female" to access the relevant array by name.

Comment: I just ended up hard coding it in there.. I did however take them all and make an array of classes that fit my needs. =)